# (Ubuntu) How to ensure that webserver has been started before the desktop environment is shown?

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, startup, live-cd, boot

I'm trying to create my own Linux distro in LiveCD format. I have put a webserver in my Linux LiveCD, and make it automatically startup during boot time.

I have made the LiveCD to auto-login to desktop environment without requiring user to type in their password.

Now, I would like to configure the web browser to automcatically pop-up during startup and show the homepage of the webserver.

I have tried different methods but i found that when user boot up the LiveCD, most of the time the desktop environment and the web browser will be shown before the webserver finished starting up. As a result, the web browser will show an error page "webpage not found/not available".

After a few seconds (after the webserver finished starting up), if the user click at the refresh button, they will be able to see the homepage.

How can I make sure that the webserver has been started up before the desktop environment is shown to the user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example, use some sort of script like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # Check existence of webserver pidfile
    pidfile="/var/run/nginx.pid"

    if [ -f $pidfile ]; then
            echo "Pidfile exists"
            < OPEN BROWSER >
    else
            echo "Web Server isn't started"
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A shell script similar to one posted by @hangover would work.

If this is only a race about couple of seconds, then another approach would be to create a local HTML file and set that as a start-up page for your web browser with a path like `file:///var/www/html/localhost/startingup.html`. The page itself would say *"Please wait while I'm finishing the startup, this will take only a short moment"*, and then forward itself to your actual web page after, say, 30 seconds.

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>Starting up...</title>
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30; http://your.actual.page/">
</head>
<body>
     <h1>Please wait, I'm still starting up.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```